# awk if statement and pattern matching

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have the next input file:

```
##Names
##Something
FVEG_04063  1265    .   AA  ATTAT   DP=19
FVEG_04063  1266    .   AA  ATTA    DP=45
FVEG_04063  2703    .   GTTTTTTTT   ATA DP=1
FVEG_15672  2456    .   TTG AA  DP=71
FVEG_01111  300 .   CTATA   ATATA   DP=7
FVEG_01111  350 .   AGAC    ATATATG DP=41
```

My desired output file:

```
##Names
##Something
FVEG_04063  1266    .   AA  ATTA    DP=45
FVEG_04063  2703    .   GTTTTTTTT   ATA DP=1
FVEG_15672  2456    .   TTG AA  DP=71
FVEG_01111  300 .   CTATA   ATATA   DP=7
FVEG_01111  350 .   AGAC    ATATATG DP=41
```

Explanation: I want to print in my output file, all the lines begining with "#", all the "unique" lines attending to column 1, and if I have repeated hits in column 1, first: take the number in $2 and sum to length of $5 (in same line), if the result is smaller than the $2 of next line, print both lines; BUT if the result is bigger than the $2 of next line, compare the values of DP and only print the line with best DP.

What I've tried:

```
awk '/^#/ {print $0;} arr[$1]++; END {for(i in arr){ if(arr[i]>1){ HERE I NEED TO INTRODUCE MORE 'IF' I THINK... } } { if(arr[i]==1){print $0;} } }' file.txt
```

I'm new in awk world... I think that is more simple to do a little script with multiple lines... or maybe is better a bash solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if three lines overlap w.r.t. $1 plus length of $5?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what do you mean, I don't want to compare the length($5) of lines with same $1, I only want to check that the sum of $2+length($5) of first line, is smaller/bigger than $2 of next line. I think that it's a bit difficult to explain myself well sorry about that

Comment: The question was whether it was always just two lines. Can't it be 3 lines or even more?

Comment: Yes... you're right. Let's say... first compare the 2 first lines, choose the best, and then compare it with the next one, and choose the best (for 3,4,5..etc lines that are repeated in $1 and the sum is bigger than $2 of next line)

Comment: Also, what should happen if you compare the DP and both lines have the same value?

Comment: I don't really know yet but... in principle, save the first one and that's all (I have to think more about that) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, an `awk` solution. I have commented the code heavily, so hopefully the comments will serve as explanation. As a summary, the basic idea is to:

- Match comment lines, print them, and go to the next line.
- Match the first line (done by checking if whether we have started remembering col1 yet).
- On all subsequent lines, check values against the remembered values from the previous line. The "best" record, ie. the one that should be printed for each unique ID, is remembered each time and updated depending on conditions set forth by the question.
- Finally, output the last "best" record of the last unique ID.

Code:

```
# Print lines starting with '#' and go to next line.
/^#/ { print $0; next; }

# Set up variables on the first line of input and go to next line.
! col1 { # If col1 is unset:
  col1 = $1; 
  col2 = $2; 
  len5 = length($5); 
  dp = substr($6, 4) + 0; # Note dp is turned into int here by +0
  best = $0; 
  next; 
}

# For all other lines of input:
{
  # If col1 is the same as previous line:
  if ($1 == col1) {
    # Check col2
    if (len5 + col2 < $2) # Previous len5 + col2 < current $2
      print best; # Print previous record
    # Check DP
    else if (substr($6, 4) + 0 < dp) # Current dp < previous dp:
      next; # Go to next record, do not update variables.
  }
  else { # Different ids, print best line from previous id and update id.
    print best;
    col1 = $1;
  }

  # Update variables to current record.
  col2 = $2;
  len5 = length($5);
  dp = substr($6, 4) + 0;
  best = $0;
}

# Print the best record of the last id.
END { print best }
```

Note: `dp` is calculated by taking the sub-string of `$6` starting at index 4 and going to the end. The `+ 0` is added to force the value to be converted to an integer, to ensure the comparison will work as expected.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for comment the code. It works nice. But there is a way to "parse" the 6 column. I mean, the fact is that sometimes I have the 6 column like: ;IS=21,0.875000;DP=24;VDB=3.627844e-02;AF1=1; and I need to take the number after DP= and the ; . I will try to do it.

Comment: I want to do something like this awk 'match($0, /DP=[0-9]*/) {print substr($0, RSTART+3, RLENGTH-3)}' file.txt (The output is all the numbers after 'DP='). And this could be the variable "dp" of your string. I hope I'm explaining... I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @cucurbit If I understand you correctly, you are saying that your column `$6` is sometimes not DP alone, but also has a number of other data including DP. Your solution was pretty close, and not hard to integrate with the code above. Here's how: replace all occurrences of `substr($6, 4)` above (there are 3 -- twice after `dp =` and once inside an `else if` statement) with `substr($0, match($0, /DP=[0-9]*/)+3, RLENGTH-3)`. This assumes that DP **must** be present on the line. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Ouuh...yes! It was pretty close but not enough. This is advanced level of awk for me :(. But the code is clear! Thanks, really.

Comment: Hi @savanto, I'm having another problem with processing this file. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution. You might need to fix the border cases as you didn't provide data to test them.

`@last` remembers the last line, `@F` is the current line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my (@F, @last);
while (<>) {
    @F = split;
    print and next if /^#/ or not @last;

    if ($last[0] eq $F[0]) {
        if ($F[1] + length $F[4] > $last[1] + length $last[4]) {
            print "@last\n";

        } else {
            my $dp_l = $last[5];
            my $dp_f = $F[5];
            s/DP=// for $dp_l, $dp_f;

            if ($dp_l > $dp_f) {
                @F = @last;
            }
        }
    } else {
        print "@last\n" if @last;
    }
} continue {
    @last = @F;
}
print "@last\n";
```

Comment: This is OK :), but I was looking for some awk/bash solution.. :S

Comment: @cucurbit: Feel free to translate it to any language you like :)